# How to test external tab completion script in Ruby

Tags: ruby, rspec

So say I have an external command, `fart`, that supports tab completion for its subcommands. When you type `fart <\tab><\tab>` in the command line, it prints out something like

```
$ > fart █
do             some             things             here              
or             other            stuff              there
```

however, if you type `fart <\enter>`, it prints the help text

```
fart is a tool for doing things and stuff

Usage: fart <command>

Commands:

  init     Initialize a new something or other
  status   Report the status of the thing
  version  Show the fart version information
```

I want to test that the tab completion works via an integration test suite in Ruby. When I tell `exec` to execute `fart \t\t`, I get the help output, not the autocomplete output. How can I get `exec` to not terminate the shell command with a newline so that I can assert the autocompletion output?

Comment: Is that really the best placeholder name you could come up with?

Comment: I don't see how it's relevant one way or the other.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't fa^M^M exec the thing. It doesn't work like this. You need to interact with a [PTY](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.1/libdoc/pty/rdoc/PTY.html). Basically spawn a shell in a PTY, then send keys like you would do interactively.

Alternatively you could write `expect` scripts and use the `expect` utility found in most linux distros.

Auto-completion is a shell function, not a program function. When you hit `tab`, `bash` or some other shell is looking for completion definitions and uses them to show you the available options. It is **not** executing the program in any way.

Comment: The purpose of these tests is only to validate that a container has the relevant tab completions installed, not to validate any behavior with the application the completions are for.

Comment: @verygoodsoftwarenotvirus, this is exactly what I write to you above